# database does not exist. but it does

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

So I wanted to install an acp on my homepage. I uploaded all needed files on my webserver (I use **FileZilla Client**) and opened phpMyAdmin with xampp. 
It connects the database but then it says

> "Database does not exist."

I'm fairly new to working with phpMyAdmin and mySQL as well.

this is what my **db.php** looks like:

```
   <?php
$host = "localhost"; // database server
$user = "akichuchan"; // db username
$pw = "cherryjuice"; // db password    
$db = "acp"; // db name     

$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pw, $db) or die ("No connection possible.");    
mysql_select_db($db, $link) or die ("Database does not exist.");     
?>
```

What did I do wrong?
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below **working** code:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; // database server
$user = "akichuchan"; // db username
$pw = "cherryjuice"; // db password    
$db = "acp"; // db name     

$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pw) or die ("No connection possible.");    
mysql_select_db($db, $link) or die ("Database does not exist.");     
?>
```

**NOTE:** Don't use **" mysql_ "**. Better to use **" PDO or Mysqli_ "** ( safe and secure ) .

Comment: Tried this one and it kinda worked but now it looks like this: [link](http://i57.tinypic.com/5up7r.png)

Comment: Okay nevermind that, I solved it. Thank you both so much :)

Comment: So what exactly you want to achieve ? and if its working then accept and / or upvote the answer.

Comment: @akichuchan, are you trying to access database on remote server ?

Comment: no I'm accessing the database from my own server and I wanted to solve those warning stuff which I did solve with your help. That was all :) Also, I tried upvoting your answer but the counter always jumps back to "0"

Comment: @akichuchan, your rep is only **8** so you can't upvote now. For upvoting min rep is **15**